# Java Executors and per-thread (not per-work unit) objects?

Tags: java, thread-safety, threadpool, executor

I have a task that would benefit from the Thread Pool design pattern (many small tasks to be performed in parallel).  I initially implemented a naive thread pool from scratch, with n Runnables all pulling work units from the same `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` until the queue is empty, then terminating. I then decided "hey, let's try the Executor in Java, because that is probably better-tested and more reliable than my naively designed system." Problem: in my implementation, each thread persisted until the queue was empty, using a while `(!queue.isEmpty())`, and got its own instance of a non-threadsafe object, let's call it `SlowObject foo`, that is time-consuming to construct.  Trying to pass all `Runnable`s that go into the `Executor`'s pool an instance of the time-inefficient object fails because it is not thread-safe.  Creating a new instance of `SlowObject` for each `Runnable` is undesirable because they are costly to construct.

Is there a way to say "how many threads are we using? Let's create one `SlowObject` for each thread, and then let the Runnables detect what thread we're on and look up the correct object to use?"  This sounds brittle and failure-prone -- not sure what design pattern I should be looking at instead, though.

Comment: Take a look at a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

Comment: Are you sure you can't quickly make a copy of `SlowObject`? Is it slow to look up the data that needs to go into it, or is it slow to construct the object once you have all the data?

Comment: @coding.mof, write your opinion as an answer. IMHO it is the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java provides the concept of a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variable.
You can use it within your [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) like this.

```
 public class MyJob implements Runnable {
     private static final ThreadLocal < SlowObject > threadLocal = 
       new ThreadLocal < SlowObject > () {
         @Override protected SlowObject initialValue() {
           // construct and return your SlowObject 
         }
       };

     public void run() {
       // work with threadLocal.get()
     }
   }
```

Thereby for each thread running your Runnable only a single instance of your class SlowObject is created.

Answer (score 4):

You're better off using a resource pool. Use something like this:

```
public class SlowObjectPool {
    private static final int POOL_SIZE = 10;
    private BlockingQueue<SlowObject> slowObjectQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(POOL_SIZE);

    public SlowObjectPool() {
        for (int i = 0; i < POOL_SIZE; i++) {
            slowObjectQueue.put(new SlowObject());
        }
    }

    public SlowObject take() throws InterruptedException {
        return slowObjectQueue.take();
    }

    public void release(SlowObject slowObject) {
        // TODO You may want to log a warning if this is false
        slowObjectQueue.offer(slowObject);
    }
}
```

You may want to make this a singleton as well. Then in your runnables:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private SlowObjectPool pool;

    public MyRunnable(SlowObjectPool pool) {
        this.pool = pool;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // The next line blocks until a SlowObject is available
        SomeObject someObject = null;
        try {
            someObject = pool.take()
            // Do something with someObject
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Thread is being ended, allow to end
        } finally {
            if (someObject != null)
                pool.release(someObject);
        }
    }
}
```

This will create the objects all at once when the pool is first created instead of creating them dynamically, that way none of your runnables have to wait for `SomeObject` instances to be created.